# Enabling XBitHack with Virtual Hosts in Apache 2.04

Tags: apache, virtualhost, apache-config, ssi

We're running Apache 2.04 as our webserver. New development with our sites is using SSI. I don't want to alter our url's, so I decided on using XBitHack.

I've come across a few suggestions online:

`XBitHack on`
`<Directory/the/sites/home>`
`Options +Includes`
 `</Directory>`

and:

`Options +Includes`
`XBitHack on`

I've tried both in the `<VirtualHost...>` context of the config file, and neither worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Directory/the/sites/home>
XBitHack on
Options +Includes
</Directory>
```